# Puppeteer => How to access all <td> in a loop on <tr> tags

Tags: puppeteer

I need to access a td with a specific value but doing so, I need to additionally determine the row number and td number where this particular value is in (the table changes in time and I need an universal approach). I thought about counting the row number and cell number in two loops, so once i find the searched value, i can extract its row and cell numbers. The question is, once I start to iterate over rows, how to access all tds of each row?

```
const rows = await page.$$('.CalendarMonthGrid > :nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  // how to iterate over the tds?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have known your table column number is exactly the same every time, then you can loop it by selecting the td only. Make a loop inside a loop is hard to maintain and basically it's slower than single loop only.
For example your table contain 5 columns.

```
let this_row, this_col;
let column = 5; // Specify your column number here
const data = await page.$$('.CalendarMonthGrid > :nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td');

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Here you can find row number for every td by doing this
    this_row = Math.ceil( (i + 1)/column )
    // Here you can find column number by doing this
    this_col = (i + 1) % column
}
```

If your table is dynamic and have unknown specific number of columns and rows, then your code will be like this.

```
let this_row, this_col;
const data = await page.$$('.CalendarMonthGrid > :nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td');
const row_num = (await page.$$('.CalendarMonthGrid > :nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)')).length;
const column = data.length / row_num;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Here you can find row number for every td by doing this
    this_row = Math.ceil( (i + 1)/column )
    // Here you can find column number by doing this
    this_col = (i + 1) % column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depends what you want to do, but this is one of ways to get index of element as well as Element (specific td in your case).

```
const rows = await page.$$('.CalendarMonthGrid > :nth-child(1) > div > table > tbody > tr');
rows.map((trNode, index) => {
   // here you have access to your node + index of it
});
```